# Filling an incomplete circles

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, matlab-cvst

I am dealing with some circles in MATLAB image processing. At one step I need to fill the circles to make them discs. I use *imfill* command to fill the circles but the circles with incomplete boundaries doesn't work with it. Can someone suggest me a technique to fill these incomplete circles?

Thank You

Comment: You could complete them first.

Comment: @knedlsepp I tried to complete them using erosion but its not working. Can you suggest me something how to complete them?

Comment: I guess you will already have tried the [first link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detect-and-measure-circular-objects-in-an-image.html) that popped up on google.

Comment: That would greatly help if you posted the actual code you use (even if it does not work properly) with a sample image so that we can try it on our own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `imfindcircles` function to detect the circles first. `imfindcircles` should work for partial circles. Then, once you know where the circles are, you can use the `insertShape` function from the Computer Vision System Toolbox to draw complete circle boundaries into your image. Then you should be able to use `imfill` to turn them into discs.